# Editing the page does not work if I use get_template_part in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Help solve the problem, please!

I have template part content-event.php. I use it in the loop of custom post type "event" in archive-event.php It works well here.

Now I need to make a carousel of these posts (events). My code in functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('km_events_carousel', 'km_events_carousel');

function km_events_carousel(){

    $html = '<div class="your-class">';

    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'km_event',
        'meta_key' => 'start',
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'    => 'ASC'
    );

    $km_events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $km_events_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $km_events_query->have_posts() ) {
            ob_start();
            get_template_part( kettlebell_get_post_template_part_slug(), 'event' );
            $html .= ob_get_clean();
        }
    }

    $html .= '</div>';

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $html;
}
```

This shortcode also works well.

**The essence of the problem:** when I click on the "Edit page" on the top of the page or open the page from the admin panel for editing, I get a picture of one of the posts that appear in the carousel instead of the admin panel.

If I comment function get_template_part() - all works correctly. But of course, then I do not get posts in the carousel.

Tell me, please, what could be the error or some workaround.

Comment: Hey @bva, hope this guide helps you: https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/using-get_template_part-in-a-shortcode/

Comment: Have you tried replacing $html .= ob_get_clean(); with just  ob_get_clean(); ?